# How to filter number and string in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

i want to filter employee details.. in that i have select option containing both number and string... i can filter string in the object but cant make it number... please guide me

```
        <select id="endDate" onchange="sortEDate()">
            <option value="All Years">All Years</option>
            <option value="Past Years">Past Years</option>
            <option value="Present">Present</option>
        </select>
        <p id="demo1"></p>
```

```
const employees = [
    { firstname: "Dav", start: 2013, end: 2018 },
    { firstname: "Gemmy", start: 2016, end: "Present" }
]
function sortEDate() {
    const filterDate = [];
    let cDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    employees.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        if (item.end === cDate) {
            filterDate.push(item);
        }
    });

    let fDate = "<table>";
    filterDate.forEach(function(filterDate) {
        fDate += "<tr>";
        fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.firstname + "</td>";
        fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.start + "</td>";
        fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.end + "</td>";
        fDate += "</tr>";
    });
    fDate += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = fDate;

    let allEducation = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    if (allEducation === "All Years") {
        showEmployees();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `employees` array

Comment: Which part of you code is producing an unexpected result, and how does that result differ from what you expected?

Comment: ```const filterDate = [];
    let cDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    employees.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        if (item.end === cDate) {
            filterDate.push(item);
        }
    });```

Answer (score 0):

In the below, if block try using `==` instead of `===`

```
if (item.end == cDate) {
    filterDate.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Since item.end can also be a number and when you are getting the value from DOM it will be a string since === checks for type as well. Because of this reason, I think you are seeing unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to make this work as expected. I used `label` as well as `value` for the `option` elements as well as passed the actual selected value to the select `onchange` handler. Also I loaded the items on `load` on the body which you can remove I just wanted them to be loaded when the page loads etc. Since you are not using jQuery it is on the `onload` event handler etc.

```js
const employees = [{
    firstname: "Dav",
    start: 2013,
    end: 2018
  },
  {
    firstname: "Gemmy",
    start: 2016,
    end: "Present"
  }
]

function filterDates(sel) {
  let filterDate = []
  sel = sel || "All"
  filterDate.push(...employees.filter(function(obj) {
    switch (sel) {
      case "All":
        return true  // return all
      case "Past":
        return obj.end < new Date().getFullYear() // just past years
      case "Present":
        return obj.end === 'Present' 
    }
  }))

  let fDate = "<table>";
  filterDate.forEach(function(filterDate) {
    fDate += "<tr>";
    fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.firstname + "</td>";
    fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.start + "</td>";
    fDate += "<td>" + filterDate.end + "</td>";
    fDate += "</tr>";
  });
  fDate += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = fDate;
}
```

```html
<body onload="filterDates()">
  <select id="endDate" onchange="filterDates(this.value);">
    <option label="All Years" value="All">All Years</option>
    <option label="Past Years" value="Past">Past Years</option>
    <option label="Present" value="Present">Present</option>
  </select>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <body/>
```

The key is the filtering which I did not want to change too much so I left how you ware doing it for the most part with the exception that now it uses Array.filter and a `switch` internally to know how to filter based on the selected option.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer resolved your question feel free to check it as the answer. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: ``` function sortEDate() {
    const filterDate = [];
    let cDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    cDate = cDate || "All Years";
    filterDate.push(...employees.filter(function(item){
        switch (cDate) {
            case "All Years":
                return true;
            case "Past Years":
                return item.end < new Date().getFullYear();
            case "Present":
                return item.end === "Present";
        }
    })); ```  it works well. pls explain why you put 3 dots before employees. i tried without dots and it is not working

Comment: This is because we need to spread the results from the filter into the ‘push’ so they are inserted and we do not push the array itself but the items individually. It is called spread operator.

Comment: OK here is an updated version without the spread operator: https://jsfiddle.net/kz63v42L/1/